# How could i check checkboxes inside anchor tag

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am working on asp.net and HTML. I have a div tag that contains 3 checkboxes. to make div clickable i have placed div tag inside anchor tag like..

```
<a href="#">
<div class="box1">
<input type="checkbox" value="xxx"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="yyy"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="zzz"/>
</div>
</a>
```

I am unable check in/out the checkboxes inside div tag due to anchor tag. it redirects me to anchor tag's href address. How could i check checkboxes inside anchor tag. please guide me.

Comment: You probably don't need the `<a>` tag to make your `<div>` clickable.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: its bad practice to put a block element in an inline element.

Comment: Why are you trying to make the div clickable? Putting form controls inside a link is all kinds of wrong, too.

Comment: HTML does not allow `<input>` elements to be descendants of `<a>` elements. Write valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

For first, your approach is bad, you can add `onclick="yourfunction()"` to make your div "clickable", then there won't be any need of `<a>`

If you really need the anchor tag `<a>` then add `return false;` to your function which you use to get the values of checkboxes. This will prevent default behaviour of navigation.